# Is it safe to delete all svchost processes?

Tags: windows, performance, svchost

On Windows 7 I ended the Network Restricted one to speed up my computer. It worked (thank god) but my computer is still a bit slow.

Is it safe to delete all the svchost processes?

Comment: No, all svchost processes run required Windows services. What in detail is slow? Boot? Starting programs?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely not!

The svchost.exe processes are, as the name implies, hosts for Windows services that don't require their own process. (They appear with the line `TYPE: 20 WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS` in the list generated by `sc query`.) Many important system functions run inside these processes, including:

- Windows Update (`wuauserv`)
- Windows Management Instrumentation (`Winmgmt`), which provides information on system components and facilitates management of the system through [its API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384642%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- Windows Defender (`WinDefend`)
- WebClient (`WebClient`), which if I remember correctly is what lets URLs appear as open-able local files for some applications
- Windows Connection Manager (`Wcmsvc`), which makes decisions about how to utilize your network adapter(s)
- Themes (`Themes`), which provides visual styles for windows
- Workstation (`LanManWorkstation`), which lets your machine connect to shared resources via the SMB protocol
- Plug and Play (`PlugPlay`), which lets your computer recognize and configure new devices; you will be extremely sad if you stop this service

Feel free to read through the output of `sc query` or open `services.msc` to see what other functions Windows services provide. **Don't kill service host processes!**